# C# Login to https Website via program

Tags: c#, post, connect

I want to login to website https://ssl.aukro.ua/enter_login.php with following credential parsing and stackoverflow1

I am using following code and it is not working

```
HttpWebRequest http = WebRequest.Create("https://ssl.aukro.ua/enter_login.php") as HttpWebRequest;
http.KeepAlive = true;
http.Method = "POST";
http.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
string postData = "user_login=" + "parsing" + "&user_password=" + "stackoverflow1";
byte[] dataBytes = UTF8Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(postData);
http.ContentLength = dataBytes.Length;
using (Stream postStream = http.GetRequestStream())
{
    postStream.Write(dataBytes, 0, dataBytes.Length);
}
HttpWebResponse httpResponse = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
// Probably want to inspect the http.Headers here first
http = WebRequest.Create("http://aukro.ua/myaccount/bid.php") as HttpWebRequest;
http.CookieContainer = new CookieContainer();
http.CookieContainer.Add(httpResponse.Cookies);
HttpWebResponse httpResponse2 = http.GetResponse() as HttpWebResponse;
```

Comment: Do you have access to the server you want to connect to? That is, are you sure their aren't other hidden fields or other variables that need to be set?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inspection of the POST when logging in reveals several other parameters:

```
cod OGZkZlVlNmJk
global_login_hash   83a8ead80c5c544c86c51ab9914db0ab891d7223
session OWFhMANRVl5dVlVUVFoDCAlTBVFQB1QNDVZQVlFTU11cUAVSVFMDDwpRVVVTVgdZCFZSA1JSYmMyOA==
session_login_hash  38d1a6b20f20d7cb7a8cf93d7f3048087d8c9ffb
url ODNiOF5HRxICHE1PQUQdA01YEFcYRlI2MzNi
user_login  test
user_password   test
version A
```

You'll need to parse these out of the login page and add them to your post.